# How to add a icon in JButton

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I'm trying to create a icon in a button in JButton, the button should look like this
[image]

But when i add this in my code it looks like this

[image]

Here is the button portion of my code

```
private JButton backButton = new JButton();
backButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    actionBack();
  }
});
backButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon(Hello.class.getResource("/239706184.png")));
backButton.setEnabled(false);
buttonPanel.add(backButton);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button is dark because you set eneable to false

remove this line:

```
backButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set `backButton.setEnabled(false);` then it will be showing in dark state.

Try it set to true.